# Setting a value from Session Variables with asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

everyone! I'm new here, and like everyone else, came for getting some help with a little project I'm working on.

My code on C# and Razor works as following: An app's user needs to perform a rating in a recipe previously stored in the DB, with the restriction that can't rate a recipe more than once.

Thing's fine, but need to add that restriction in conjunction with the user that's rating the recipe. I got a DropDown list that lists all users and can do the submit into DB and all, but I want that the user that's logged in submits the form, and no one else or being "selectable", that's how's working for now.

I'm using session variables for getting the user's ID and general info, but I can't get it into work, because the foreign key assosiates to that, and when I try to retrieve it manually, I got only the ID (that's the foreign key in the table), but need to show who's doing the submit and not the ID, even if is requiered in a HiddenFor.

How can I solve this little problem? Any help is truly appreciated :)

The GET and POST methods from recetastblController.cs

```
    // GET: recetastbl/Rate
    public ActionResult Rate(usuariostbl usuariostbl)
    {
        var puntuaciontbl = db.puntuaciontbl.Include(p => p.recetastbl).Include(p => p.usuariostbl);

        ViewBag.usuariostbl = Session["usuarioConectado"];
        ViewBag.usuariostbl_id = ViewBag.usuariostbl.id;
        ViewBag.usuariostbl.username = ViewBag.usuariostbl.username;

        ViewBag.usuariostbl_id = new SelectList(db.usuariostbl, "id", "username");
        ViewBag.recetastbl_id = new SelectList(db.recetastbl, "id", "receta");

        return View();
    }

    // POST: recetastbl/Rate
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Rate([Bind(Include = "id,valoracion,usuariostbl_id,recetastbl_id")] puntuaciontbl puntuaciontbl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.puntuaciontbl.Add(puntuaciontbl);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.usuariostbl_id = new SelectList(db.usuariostbl, "id", "username", puntuaciontbl.usuariostbl_id);
        ViewBag.recetastbl_id = new SelectList(db.recetastbl, "id", "receta", puntuaciontbl.recetastbl_id);

        return View("Index");
    }
```

The full view Rate.cshtml

```
@model Prueba3Progra4.puntuaciontbl

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Valorar Receta";
}

<h2>Valorar</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Receta</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.valoracion, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            1 Estrella
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.valoracion, "1", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            2 Estrellas
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.valoracion, "2", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            3 Estrellas
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.valoracion, "3", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            4 Estrellas
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.valoracion, "4", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            5 Estrellas
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.valoracion, "5", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.valoracion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.usuariostbl_id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("usuariostbl_id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.usuariostbl_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.recetastbl_id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("recetastbl_id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.recetastbl_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Valorar" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Volver a la Lista", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Your code sample is a bit confusing.  Your controller action sets the view bag properties, but your razor code looks like the view is bound to a model.  My speculation on your difficulty is that your actions are disconnected.  If you use separate get/post controller methods then model binding you can pass this information from client to server without needing to use the viewbag or session state.  I can post an example here if you would like.

Comment: Yeah, sure! :) I posted only the GET call because I think it would be easier to understand, but seems not hahaha. I will attach it to the main post so you can check it better. Or should I add the full code for both files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ViewBag object is intended for giving the view data to work with.

For get/post operations, binding the views to a view model will be much better in the long run.  For example:

The View Model:

```
    public class usuarioConectado
    {
        public string usuariostbl_id { get; set; } // 'hidden for'
        public string username { get; set; } // 'hidden for'
        [Display(Name = "Valoracion")]
        public ICollection<string> valoracion { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Usuarios Id")]
        public ICollection<string> usuariostbl_id_list { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Recetas Id")]
        public ICollection<string> recetastbl_id_list { get; set; }
    }
```

The Controller:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult Rate()
    {
        return View(GetNewModel());
    }
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Rate(usuarioConectado model)
    {
        ///
        /// When the user posts the form,
        /// the model parameter will have all
        /// of the values set in the 'get' method,
        /// along with the items selected.
        ///
        SaveModel(model);
        return View(GetNewModel());
    }
    private usuarioConectado GetNewModel()
    {
        return new usuarioConectado()
        {
            recetastbl_id_list = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" },
            usuariostbl_id_list = new List<string>() { "4", "5", "6" },
            valoracion = new List<string>() { "7", "8", "9" },
            username = "usuario1",
            usuariostbl_id = "1",
        };
    }
    private void SaveModel(usuarioConectado model)
    {
        //Save Stuff
    }
```

The View:

```
@model MVCAnswers.Models.usuarioConectado


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Ans40824091";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Default.cshtml";
}

<h2>Ans40824091</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Rate", "Ans40824091"))
    {
        <div class="form-group >
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.usuariostbl_id_list, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.usuariostbl_id_list, new SelectList(Model.usuariostbl_id_list, Model.usuariostbl_id_list), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.usuariostbl_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.recetastbl_id_list, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.recetastbl_id_list, new SelectList(Model.recetastbl_id_list, Model.recetastbl_id_list), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.recetastbl_id_list, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.valoracion, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.valoracion, new SelectList(Model.valoracion, Model.valoracion), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.valoracion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <h2>Hidden:</h2>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.Hidden("username", Model.username)
                @Html.Hidden("usuariostbl_id", Model.usuariostbl_id)
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
```

Caution:
Using 'hidden' input on a form has some risks regarding security.  But if you perform validation on the http post and the risk should be really small.